# Haskell function that returns prime factors of n

Tags: haskell, factors

I am trying to learn Haskell by creating some basic functions. The function that I am currently trying to work on is called `primeFactors` and it needs to return a list of the prime factors for a given number n. Currently I have the following:

```
factors :: Integral a => a -> [a]
factors n = [x | x <- [1..n], n `mod` x == 0]

isPrime :: Integral a => a -> Bool
isPrime n = factors n == [1, n]

primeFactors :: Integral a => a -> [a]
primeFactors n = []
```

I figure I should use the first two functions, but I'm not exactly sure how to do so. Functional programming is totally new to me.

In the end if I call it like so: `primeFactors 10` I expect it to return `[5, 2]`

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "factors" only needs to consider x <- [1 .. (n+1) `div` 2]. Think about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the "filter" function. It has this type:

```
filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
```

The first argument is the predicate and the second is the list you are filtering. The result is a list containing only those elements for which the predicate returns True. So you can write any of the following:

```
primeFactors n = filter isPrime (factors n)

primeFactors n = filter isPrime $ factors n

primeFactors = filter isPrime . factors
```

The first one should be self explanatory. The second uses the "$" operator, which is just function application with a zero precedence. Its often used to get rid of brackets in the trailing expression. The last is in "point-free" style (the term comes from topology: roughly speaking a point is a variable). The "." operator is defined like this:

```
(f . g) x = f (g x)
```

If you substitute "filter isPrime" for "f" and "factors" for "g" into that you will see how it works.

Comment: I ended up doing the following but your way is much cleaner:
```primeFactors n = [x | x <- [1..n], n `mod` x == 0 && isPrime x]```

Comment: could you possibly help me with this one?
``nextPrime :: Integral a => a -> a``
``nextPrime n = n`` It has to return the next prime after n

Comment: You can do it with dropWhile: `nextPrime n = head . dropWhile (<=n) $ filter isPrime [1..]`. After the `$`, a list of primes is generated on the fly (lazy evaluation: only that what is needed is calculated). Then, we filter out every value less or equal to `n`, because you want the next prime. Then, we take the head, because we only need 1.

Comment: @RenZeee: that will work, but it will still have computed all the primes. Better would be to start generating candidates from "n".

Comment: Good one, then: `nextPrime n = head $ filter isPrime [n..]` if `n` is allowed too.